# How to create a complex html+css nav that will resize appropriately

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I want to create a container so that i have a simple layout with a nav bar at the top and a nav bar on the left side which is about 150px. As the screen gets smaller though, i want the left nav to entirely disappear and have the following occur:

1) Replace the 150px (icon + text) nav bar with just an icon nav bar on the left

or 2) remove/hide the nav bar entirely and have a burger bar in the top nav which will expand a vertical menu down. This would be the exact same menu as the one before on the left except it would not be displayed from the top nav rather than the side.

What i've done so fat?

```css
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Awesome Bootstrap 3 Sidebar Navigation</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">


    /* MORE THAN 75 */
    
    body {
      background-color: skyBlue;
    }
    /* LESS THAN 75 */
    
    @media (max-width: 74.9em) {
      body {
        background-color: pink;
      }
    }
    /* LESS THAN 62 */
    
    @media (max-width: 61.9em) {
      body {
        background-color: blue;
      }
    }
    /* LESS THAN 48 */
    
    @media (max-width: 47.9em) {
      body {
        background-color: green;
      }
    }
    /* LESS THAN 34 */
    
    @media (max-width: 33.9em) {
      body {
        background-color: red;
      }
    }
    
    .navbar-outer {
      width: 600px;
    }
    
    .aav {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: red;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row aav">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2" style="width:100px; border:solid; color:white;">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-10">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  </div>
```

I'm trying to create the left nav and the content pane. I'm thinking too much of java i guess because i'm not sure how to go about the implementation. Any feedback is appreciated.

I'm stuck because i don't want the left bar to scale, i want it to be a fixed width until the screen gets too small for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complicated question, but the gist of it is that you can set a container (or just set styles on the `body` element itself) to hold your nav, sidebar, and general content area, and then modify their widths and heights with media queries.

So given your page is 100vw across, for example, your sidebar could be 150px wide as you mentioned, and that would leave 100vw - 150px for the width of the main content area. You'd float them next to each other.

```
main {
  width: 100vw;
}
aside {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}
section {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
}
```

When you want the sidebar to narrow, you can adjust the width of the sidebar and the calc expression for the main content area. (You'd also hide the labels next to your icons.)

```
@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
  aside {
    width: 40px;
  }
  section {
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
  }
}
```

When you get to mobile view, your sidebar can simply become 100% width of the screen, and then you'll need additional CSS to change the display of the icons and whatnot.

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  aside {
    width: 100%;
  }
  section {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

That's the general principle you'll want to work with, but a lot of the other CSS will probably depend exactly on your site. Below is an example.

```css
main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
nav {
  background-color: #5BA1CB;
  height: 80px;
}
nav .title {
  width: 130px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  float: left;
}
nav .burger {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}
nav .burger img {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
aside {
  background-color: #144360;
  width: 150px;
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  float: left;
}
aside .icon {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
aside .icon:first-child {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
aside .icon span,
aside .icon img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
section {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #DAEAF4;
}
@media all and (max-width: 900px) and (min-width: 601px) {
  aside {
    width: 40px;
  }
  aside .icon span {
    display: none;
  }
  section {
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  aside {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
  }
  aside .icon {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
  }
  aside .icon:first-child {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  section {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <nav>
    <div class="title"><span>Title Area</span></div>
    <div class="burger">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60?text=BURGER" />
    </div>
  </nav>
  <aside>
    <div class="icon">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/25x25" />
      <span>Label</span>
    </div>
    <div class="icon">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/25x25" />
      <span>Label</span>
    </div>
    <div class="icon">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/25x25" />
      <span>Label</span>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <section>
    <h1>Body</h1>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Complicated but a good learning experience, i didn't know you could use the `@media` tag that way. Thank you, i'll play around with the code snippet you uploaded. It will help a lot :D I'll try to add the bootstrap parts myself and i'll update here later on. I hope i can ask you again if i run into trouble, thanks again.

Comment: Sure can, just leave a comment if you have a problem. You might also trying just Googling about CSS media queries if you haven't already. Should be some good info on W3Schools, Mozilla Developer Network, and plenty of other websites. Good luck!